# Manipulation before integrating by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

If it is given that$$\int_0^4e^{(x-2)^4}dx=A
$$ Then find the value of $$ \int_0^4xe^{(x-2)^4}dx$$

How do we manipulate the integral so that integration by parts can be used thereafter? Letting $x$ be $u$ does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Using $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx,$$

$$I=\int_0^4xe^{(x-2)^4}dx=\int_0^4(4+0-x)e^{(4+0-x-2)^4}dx=\int_0^4(4-x)e^{(x-2)^4}dx$$

$$\implies I=4\int_0^4e^{(x-2)^4}dx-I$$